# Not able to install Sonata Project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata

I recently came across [Sanota Project](https://sonata-project.org/get-started) and wanted to give it a try. I am trying to install all the bundles of sanota project following the quick installation steps mentioned [here](https://sonata-project.org/get-started)

and when I run the website `php app/console server:run` all i see is the white screen. I dont see any error in `app_dev.log`

I cross checked if the bundles are enabled in `Appkernel.php` and they seem to be.

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // SYMFONY STANDARD EDITION
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),

            // DOCTRINE
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),

            // KNP HELPER BUNDLES
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),

            // USER
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
            new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),

            // PAGE
            new Sonata\PageBundle\SonataPageBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\PageBundle\ApplicationSonataPageBundle(),

            // NEWS
            new Sonata\NewsBundle\SonataNewsBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\ApplicationSonataNewsBundle(),

            // MEDIA
            new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),
            // new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),

            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),

            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),

            // Disable this if you don't want the audit on entities
            new SimpleThings\EntityAudit\SimpleThingsEntityAuditBundle(),

            // API
            new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
            new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(),

            // E-COMMERCE
            new Sonata\BasketBundle\SonataBasketBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\BasketBundle\ApplicationSonataBasketBundle(),
            new Sonata\CustomerBundle\SonataCustomerBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\CustomerBundle\ApplicationSonataCustomerBundle(),
            new Sonata\DeliveryBundle\SonataDeliveryBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\DeliveryBundle\ApplicationSonataDeliveryBundle(),
            new Sonata\InvoiceBundle\SonataInvoiceBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\InvoiceBundle\ApplicationSonataInvoiceBundle(),
            new Sonata\OrderBundle\SonataOrderBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\OrderBundle\ApplicationSonataOrderBundle(),
            new Sonata\PaymentBundle\SonataPaymentBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\PaymentBundle\ApplicationSonataPaymentBundle(),
            new Sonata\ProductBundle\SonataProductBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\ApplicationSonataProductBundle(),
            new Sonata\PriceBundle\SonataPriceBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
            new FOS\CommentBundle\FOSCommentBundle(),
            new Sonata\CommentBundle\SonataCommentBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\ApplicationSonataCommentBundle(),

            // SONATA CORE & HELPER BUNDLES
            new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
            new Sonata\FormatterBundle\SonataFormatterBundle(),
            new Sonata\CacheBundle\SonataCacheBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Sonata\SeoBundle\SonataSeoBundle(),
            new Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle(),
            new Sonata\NotificationBundle\SonataNotificationBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\ApplicationSonataNotificationBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\SeoBundle\ApplicationSonataSeoBundle(),
            new Sonata\DatagridBundle\SonataDatagridBundle(),

            // Search Integration
            //new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),

            // CMF Integration
            new Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\RoutingBundle\CmfRoutingBundle(),

            // DEMO and QA - Can be deleted
            new Sonata\Bundle\DemoBundle\SonataDemoBundle(),
            new Sonata\Bundle\QABundle\SonataQABundle(),

            // Disable this if you don't want the timeline in the admin
            new Spy\TimelineBundle\SpyTimelineBundle(),
            new Sonata\TimelineBundle\SonataTimelineBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\TimelineBundle\ApplicationSonataTimelineBundle(), // easy extends integration

            new Mopa\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\MopaBootstrapBundle()
        );
```

No matter what route i access

```
/blog
/page
/media
/admin
```

All i see is white screen and no error in `app_dev.log`.

I am using Ubuntu with xampp, all other symfony projects are working fine, except this Sonata Project. My xampp logs also do not mention any error that could be causing this. In fact i cleared my log files so only Sonata related errors are logged if any and at the moments all log files are empty too.

**While trying to install using composer**

`composer create-project sonata-project/sandbox:dev-2.4-develop`

or

`composer create-project sonata-project/sandbox:dev-2.3-develop`

or

`composer create-project sonata-project/sandbox:2.3.x-dev`

I get the following error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ~2.0@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.0.x-dev].
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 2.0.x-dev requires symfony/symfony >=2.0,<2.1 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

I followed [these](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/blob/2.3-develop/README.md) instructions as well but no luck.

Since this is my first time with Sonata so I might be doing something wrong. I will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Did you execute `composer install`?

Comment: @Rvanlaak yes I did try installing using composer but that led me to another issue that I can't move on from. I have updated my question to mention the error that i am facing while using composer

Answer (score 1):

You have to change in file **composer.json**, line 34 to:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.0.*",
```

After that enter this command in sandbox folder:

```
composer update
```

Comment: Worked for me, it appears they've changed the namespace of the bundle!

Comment: I will try this today and get back

Comment: okay so I have a question, their documentation says to install sanota run a command, like i said this is my first time with sanota so I am assuming the symfony gets installed with sanota command as well, if my understanding is true how do you go and change the `composer.json`? is it after i see the error during the installing because till then the files do get downloaded. and if i change the line 34 to what you are saying, then what command do i run to continue the process?

Comment: In sonata folder you need to enter this command:
composer update

Comment: @ptyskju that does not help

Answer (score 0):

The [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) of the project you try to install is set to a option higher than `dev`. So composer will not be able to install this project.

First try to install a stable version of the project, and try to upgrade to a `dev` version afterwards by changing the `minimum-stability` to `dev`.

```
composer create-project sonata-project/sandbox
```

I'd advise you to also set `prefer-stable` to true, so the other packages will not all switch to the `dev-master` branch.

Comment: yes I did try this as well and i got an error `[InvalidArgumentException]                                            
  Could not find package sonata-project/sandbox with stability stable. `